# Dynamodb- Adding non key attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I want to insert data into dynamodb local. However, I have only one key attribute and multiple non-key attributes.

```
{
    'id':'99876983ydbhdu3739',
    'category':'Spa',
    'latitude':'33.498',
    'longitude':'32.332',
    'name':'Studio'
}
```

I have multiple such values. This is one record, an example of what I want to insert. Following is what I am trying:

```
table = dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName='Trial',
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'facebook_id',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'  #Sort key
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'latitude',
            'KeyType': 'RANGE'  #Sort key
        },

    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
         {
            'AttributeName':'id',
            'AttributeType':'S'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'category',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'latitude',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'longitude',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'name',
            'AttributeType':'S'
        }

    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 10
    }
)
```

I get the following error:

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTable operation: The number of attributes in key schema must match the number of attributesdefined in attribute definitions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can just create the table with HASH and RANGE key attributes alone while creating the table. DynamoDB doesn't expect to define all the other attributes as DynamoDB is a key-value pair table. Please try the below code. You should be able to create the table.

While inserting an item, you can include any attributes as per your requirement.

**Create Table :-**

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
    region : "us-west-2",
    endpoint : "http://localhost:8000"
});

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var params = {
    TableName : "Trail",
    KeySchema : [ {
        AttributeName : "facebook_id",
        KeyType : "HASH"
    }, //Partition key
    {
        AttributeName : "latitude",
        KeyType : "RANGE"
    } //Sort key
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions : [ {
        AttributeName : "facebook_id",
        AttributeType : "N"
    }, {
        AttributeName : "latitude",
        AttributeType : "S"
    } ],
    ProvisionedThroughput : {
        ReadCapacityUnits : 10,
        WriteCapacityUnits : 10
    }
};

dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        if (err.code === "ResourceInUseException"
                && err.message === "Cannot create preexisting table") {
            console.log("message ====>" + err.message);
        } else {
            console.error("Unable to create table. Error JSON:", JSON
                    .stringify(err, null, 2));
        }

    } else {
        console.log("Created table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(
                data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

**Create Item:-**

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
    region : "us-west-2",
    endpoint : "http://localhost:8000"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var table = "Trail";

var params = {
    TableName : table,
    Item : {
        "facebook_id" : 1,
        "latitude" : 'lat',
        "longitude" : 'long',
        "name" : 'facebook',
        "category" : 'social_media'
    }
};

console.log("Adding a new item...");
docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,
                null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Comment: But why there is an option to define attributes when creating a table at all?

Answer (score 0):

For Boto3 Users in Python:

```
ddb_client.create_table(
    TableName=DDB_TABLE_NAME,
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'id',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'latitude',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },
    ],
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'id',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'latitude',
            'KeyType': 'RANGE'
        }
    ],
    BillingMode='<your_value>'
)


response = ddb_client.put_item(
    TableName=DDB_TABLE_NAME,
    Item={
        'id': {'S': '1'},
        'latitude': {'S': '33.498'},
        'longitude': {'S': '32.332'},
        'category': {'S': 'Spa'},
        'name': {'S': 'Studio'}
    }
)
```